# Cannot get admob working: configChanges error

Tags: android, admob

I know there are some topics about it, but the reason I start this one is I appear not to be able to solve it with solutions given. I want to add admob to my project. I downloaded GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1 and added it to my project. When I startup it says You must have `AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest with configChanges`. So solution found, set it to:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

and

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Clean it, try again. But now I get an error saying following although my targetSdkVersion is set to be min 12, I really don't know why I am still getting this error:

```
String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|
 screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize')
```

Any ideas on this? There might be another setting wrong which I looked over?

Comment: minSdkVersion < 13 is incompatible with screenSize and smallestScreenSize. plus, minSdkVersion < 8 doesn't like uiMode. (i think)

Comment: I thought minSdkVersion didn't matter and the target was the one which was important for this?

Comment: not sure. i suggest you try

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your `project.properties` file, you need to the project target, as such

`target=android-15`

And then once you are done doing that, clean your project

Comment: You have any other ideas maybe?

Comment: A couple, but they are unlikely to work, first try downloading the newest version of the SDK and trying with that, if that doesn't work, I am clueless, but just as a shot in the dark try updating eclipse and ADT,

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and go to Properties. Then click to Android tab. Select you target to be at least 13 and you are done!